# Count number of rows between filled values in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm still pretty new to pandas. I would like to count the number of rows with zero values up to the next row with a value in it. So for example, I would like to take a dataframe that looks like this:

```
id   Distance
00   0   
01   0   
02   0   
03   0   
04   0   
05   10   
06   0   
07   0   
08   0   
09   0   
10   16   
11   0   
12   0   
13   6
```

and have it be transformed into this:

```
id    Distance     count
05    10            6
10    16            6
13    6             3
```

thanks

Comment: What have you tried? I would start with something like ```non_zeros = np.nonzero(data.Distance.values)```. Now it's possible to use a simple loop to count the values you want.

Comment: I was able to get it to work with a for loop, but it was incredibly clunky. I'll look into nonzero, haven't heard of it before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code achieves what you want. Notice that you need that `.copy()` because `counts` is modified on the fly.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Distance': [0,0,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,0,16,0,0,6]})

non_zeros = df['Distance'].values != 0
zeros = ~non_zeros

counts = np.cumsum(zeros)[non_zeros]
counts[1:] -= counts[:-1].copy()

df = df[non_zeros]
df['count'] = counts

print(df)
```

This code produces the output

```
    Distance  count
5         10      5
10        16      4
13         6      2
```

You may want to add a `+1` to the `count` column.